# Base UserControl with controls - incorrect alignment in derived control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to build base control that will be used to build other controls.
Idea is to add common functionality to base.

I've build base using `Add>User Control` in Visual studio. My control has 4 buttons in top-right corner and they all are anchored to top-right:

[image]

below is my control code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LayoutManager
{
    public partial class BasePanel : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler<Direction> Expand;

        public BasePanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected virtual void OnExpand(Direction e)
        {
            var handler = Expand;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }

        private void Right(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnExpand(Direction.Right);
        }

        private void Left(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnExpand(Direction.Left);
        }

        private void Up(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnExpand(Direction.Up);
        }

        private void Down(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnExpand(Direction.Down);
        }
    }
}
```

and designer code:

```
namespace LayoutManager
{
    partial class BasePanel
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.rightBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.leftBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.upBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.downBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // rightBtn
            // 
            this.rightBtn.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.rightBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
            this.rightBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(185, 27);
            this.rightBtn.Name = "rightBtn";
            this.rightBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 23);
            this.rightBtn.TabIndex = 0;
            this.rightBtn.Text = "►";
            this.rightBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.rightBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Right);
            // 
            // leftBtn
            // 
            this.leftBtn.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.leftBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
            this.leftBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(160, 27);
            this.leftBtn.Name = "leftBtn";
            this.leftBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 23);
            this.leftBtn.TabIndex = 1;
            this.leftBtn.Text = "◄";
            this.leftBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.leftBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Left);
            // 
            // upBtn
            // 
            this.upBtn.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.upBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
            this.upBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(160, 3);
            this.upBtn.Name = "upBtn";
            this.upBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 23);
            this.upBtn.TabIndex = 3;
            this.upBtn.Text = "▲";
            this.upBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.upBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Up);
            // 
            // downBtn
            // 
            this.downBtn.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.downBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
            this.downBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(185, 3);
            this.downBtn.Name = "downBtn";
            this.downBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 23);
            this.downBtn.TabIndex = 4;
            this.downBtn.Text = "▼";
            this.downBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.downBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Down);
            // 
            // BasePanel
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.Controls.Add(this.downBtn);
            this.Controls.Add(this.upBtn);
            this.Controls.Add(this.leftBtn);
            this.Controls.Add(this.rightBtn);
            this.Name = "BasePanel";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(211, 140);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button rightBtn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button leftBtn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button upBtn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button downBtn;
    }
}
```

When I add second control and set it to extend BasePanel:

```
public partial class MyPanel : BasePanel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I get this control:

[image]

but buttons that in base are in top-right corner aren't aligned correctly anymore.
I can't change buttons properties because they are locked (after clicking on then I can see little lock in top-left corner)

How should I create base UserControl that has other controls (buttons in my case) and how I should extend it to get all controls properly aligned in derived control?

**EDIT:** I using VS2013 Pro Update 4

Comment: Can I ask an off-topic question, what is `EventHandler<Direction>` you're using ? Can't find it. BTW tested your code and everything seem ok :)

Comment: @NamBình code works fine, but in VS everything is incorrectly aligned (see second picture, those buttons should be aligned to top-right) That event handler is generic handler. You can use `EventHandler<T>` and pass type as T. This way when You subscribe to event You will get that type in event args. I hope this makes is a bit clear.

Comment: The Anchor property does not do what you hope it does in this scenario, you don't like the SuspendLayout() call that the designer auto-generates.  Or in other words, in anchors to the original size, not the new size you assigned in the derived control.  Not much you can do about that, the simplest workaround is overriding OnResize() and assign the buttons' Location property.  If you still want to tinker with the buttons in the derived control then you have to change their Modifiers property from Private to Protected.

Comment: @HansPassant so that's another VS limitation. What if I'd add those buttons in constructor of my base class?

Comment: Hmya, "VS sucks" never gets you anywhere.  There were two ways they could do it, somebody always is going to be unhappy.  I recommended a workaround, I suggest you use it.

Comment: @HansPassant You're right, complaining won't get me anywhere. I didn't thank You before for Your suggestion. Thank You for that. As a temporary workaround I've set size of Base UserControl in VS to `300;300` and to all derived controls. This way alignment is done correctly. This was the easiest solution for me. It's shame VS isn't supporting this kind of stuff, but I can live with it :)

Comment: @Misiu Set the `Modifiers` of the buttons to `Protected`, as also mentioned by Hans. What's the problem?

Comment: Settings modifiers helps - buttons are aligned correctly, but they are editable in control that is derived from `BasePanel`. What I'd like to get is behavior where I can create my base control, add all buttons (and other controls) to it and "lock it" so that in derived control user wont be able to edit any controls (just like when Modifiers are set to Private),  Hope this explain bit more my idea. I don't mind designer specific code (custom designer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Panel` as container of buttons In `BasePanel`. Then set `Dock` property of panel to `Top` and put your `Button` controls in the panel and set their `Anchor` property to `Top, Right`.

This way, when you inherit from `BasePanel`, all controls including the container panel and buttons are private and can not be edited, but the designer respects to positioning of controls.

[image]

You also can remove designer of panel and buttons, so they will be transparent to mouse at designer:

```
public BasePanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(this.panel1, new DesignerAttribute(typeof(object)));
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(this.button1, new DesignerAttribute(typeof(object)));
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(this.button2, new DesignerAttribute(typeof(object)));
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(this.button3, new DesignerAttribute(typeof(object)));
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(this.button4, new DesignerAttribute(typeof(object)));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much for answering. This solves movement and alignement problem, but is it possible to "hide" that top panel (and it content) from designer? I don't mind writing designer-specific code. I'd like that top panel to be visible but not select'able and only remaining part would be editable (user will be able to put controls there). Similar to this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37830/Designing-Nested-Controls

Comment: Awesome! I don't know (yet) how it works, but I can't select those buttons in designer. One more thing: is it possible to remap design surface of my control? I have panel that contains buttons and it is 50px height, I want design surface of by control not to include that space, so user will be able to put controls only in space with no header (starting from 50 pixels from top). I've tried setting padding top of my control to 50, but that also moves panel with buttons down. Basically I want design surface of control to start just below panel with buttons

Comment: If you don't remove designer of panel, then it will prevent from a control drop on panel surface. The panel will be selectable but can not be changed due its protection level. User can not move controls above the panel by mouse but they can move controls above panel by keyboard or changing location property.

Comment: Sorry for such late reply. I'd like to clarify my last comment. I'd like my control to behave like standard GroupBox - when You add Button to GroupBox and try to position it You get blue lines (rulers) when You move Button near GroupBox edge, on top that ruler is summing padding and header height. Same when You do Dock=Fill, it isn't filling whole GroupBox, it leaves header visible. I'd like to have header in my control always visible and be able to place controls everywhere except in header (same as in GroupBox). I hope all this make sense now.

Comment: No problem :) I believe my last comment satisfies what you mentioned. Comment this line: `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(this.panel1 ...` and then you will see if you try drop a button on `panel1` you can't but you can drop a  button on design surface of your inherited control. Also you will see snaplines are working good and when you try to move the button, it will see snapline pf panel1. Also if you set dock of the button to fill, it fills the area which is not filled by panel1.

Comment: By the way, I personally prefer to avoid visual inheritance and in such case I will create a `TopBar` component which contains some behavior and then each time I need such behavior, Instead of inheriting from `TopBar`, simply I put a `TopBar` on a user control. If you need some interaction between `TopBar` and user control, you can have a property of type `TopBar` in your base user-control and assign component to it. I've used such technique over and over again and I really prefer it over visual inheritance.

Comment: If you also agree, I personally prefer to remove the second part of answer. It's better to keep the current thread specific to the `Alignment` problem which is main focus of the question and have the second part as a new question because now the answer has 2 completely different parts. Let me know if you decided to ask another question about second part of answer and I'll post this part of answer for your new question :)

Comment: No problem with that :) Your answer is fine, I'll probably will ask second question related to positioning components in UserControls. If I do I'll post link to it here. Thank You again.